# Include level number in style format definitions?

Tags: stylesheet, style

I would like to prepend a heading style (from Title down to subsubsection) with the level number corresponding to the Alt key shortcut: I lose track of what level I am at. How might this be achieved? Can it be done via the stylesheet?

Are there other ways to give visibility to the hierarchy in use?

Comment: I didn't refer to any absolute level, I referred to the numeric key value associated with the alt- combination for that style. I see items can be *numbered* (sequentially); I would like styles numbered absolutely by the alt-key equivalent.

Comment: Ah, I see now, this info is stored e.g.: `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Input", MenuCommandKey}]` where would you like to display it?

Comment: I would like that number to prefix (maybe with an optional surrounding [ ] or suffice like " - ") whatever text I type as the Title, Chapter, Subchapter, etc.